# register_globals error in php

Tags: php, php.ini

I was stuck up with the error

```
directive 'register_globals' is no longer available in PHP in unknown on line 0
```

when tried to check the php version using "php -v" after enabling `register_globals` in php.ini file. I am not getting any php version info by doing so. Instead it throws the above mentioned error.After turning off this option, php info works quite well. It is very essential for me to have register_globals to be turned on.How can I have this corrected.

my `php.ini` is as follows:

```
; Default Value: None
; Development Value: "GP"
; Production Value: "GP"
; http://php.net/request-order
request_order = "GP"

; Whether or not to register the EGPCS variables as global variables.  You may
; want to turn this off if you don't want to clutter your scripts' global scope
; with user data.
; You should do your best to write your scripts so that they do not require
; register_globals to be on;  Using form variables as globals can easily lead
; to possible security problems, if the code is not very well thought of.
; 
register_globals = On

; Determines whether the deprecated long $HTTP_*_VARS type predefined variables
; are registered by PHP or not. As they are deprecated, we obviously don't
; recommend you use them. They are on by default for compatibility reasons but
; they are not recommended on production servers.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; 
register_long_arrays = Off

; This directive determines whether PHP registers $argv & $argc each time it
; runs. $argv contains an array of all the arguments passed to PHP when a script
; is invoked. $argc contains an integer representing the number of arguments
; that were passed when the script was invoked. These arrays are extremely
; useful when running scripts from the command line. When this directive is
; enabled, registering these variables consumes CPU cycles and memory each time
; a script is executed. For performance reasons, this feature should be disabled
; on production servers.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to On for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
;
register_argc_argv = Off

; When enabled, the SERVER and ENV variables are created when they're first
; used (Just In Time) instead of when the script starts. If these variables
; are not used within a script, having this directive on will result in a
; performance gain. The PHP directives register_globals, register_long_arrays,
; and register_argc_argv must be disabled for this directive to have any affect.
;
auto_globals_jit = On
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php):

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

You can either downgrade PHP, or remove `register_globals` from your php.ini file and fix any code which refers to it. The latter is preferable.

Comment: Or to be specific.  He needs to comment out/remove any reference to `register_globals` from his ini files.

Answer (score 1):

The directive [register_gobals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0 (for a good reason: It can easily lead to security holes if you don't create high quality code)

You **cannot** enable the register_gobals option in PHP 5.4 anymore. So If you really need to have all variables registered global in some scripts, you need to simulate the old behaviour:

Create the script `php5.4-workaround.inc.php`

```
<?php
// workaround for register_globals PHP 5.4:

/**
 * function to emulate the register_globals setting in PHP
 * for all of those diehard fans of possibly harmful PHP settings :-)
 * @author Ruquay K Calloway
 * @param string $order order in which to register the globals, e.g. 'egpcs' for default
 */
function register_globals($order = 'egpcs')
{
    // define a subroutine
    if(!function_exists('register_global_array'))
    {
        function register_global_array(array $superglobal)
        {
            foreach($superglobal as $varname => $value)
            {
                global $$varname;
                $$varname = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    $order = explode("\r\n", trim(chunk_split($order, 1)));
    foreach($order as $k)
    {
        switch(strtolower($k))
        {
            case 'e':    register_global_array($_ENV);        break;
            case 'g':    register_global_array($_GET);        break;
            case 'p':    register_global_array($_POST);        break;
            case 'c':    register_global_array($_COOKIE);    break;
            case 's':    register_global_array($_SERVER);    break;
        }
    }
}
register_globals();
?>
```

On debians `php.ini` the `include_path` contains `/usr/share/php` so this if you put your script there, you can include it in all scripts you need:

```
<?php include("/usr/share/php/php5.4-workaround.inc.php"); ?>
```